# Remove ↵ from JSON in web api + AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, json.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using web API 2 + AngularJS to return my data to angular controllers but I don't know why I keep getting this character ↵ in my json result.

My ASP controller has this method.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetAditionalFieldCOnfiguration()
    {
        var ListAdditionalFields = new List<rgAdditionalField>() 
        { 
            new rgAdditionalField(){  Type="text", Label="Nombre", Model="first", Val="Carlo" },
            new rgAdditionalField(){  Type="text", Label="Apellido", Model="last", Val="Carlos prueba"},
            new rgAdditionalField(){  Type="text", Label="Direc", Model="direccion", Val="los alpes"},
        };

        return Ok(ListAdditionalFields);
    }
```

and I got this in my angular controller (I tried with $http, $resource and Restangular and got the same result):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/LBAn3y3.jpg]

I tried different configurations in my WebApiConfig but nothing works, configuration:

```
 public static JsonSerializerSettings GetSettingListFormat(rgJsonSettingType type)
    {

        switch (type)
        {
            case rgJsonSettingType.List:
                return new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };                    
            case rgJsonSettingType.Single:
                return new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore };                    
            case rgJsonSettingType.SingleCamelCase:
                return new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects, ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };
            case rgJsonSettingType.ListCamelCase:
                return new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore, ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() };

        }

        return new JsonSerializerSettings();
    }
```

I tried with HttpResponseMessage and it returns:

```
return   Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ListAdditionalFields, JsonConfiguration.....)
```

and nothing else.

Can you help me please?

Comment: Isn't it just your debug tool or whatever that indicates you there's a carriage return ?

Comment: But why my code works in mvc controller but web api controller dont, i got different result with same json configuration.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's behind your controller from AngularJS, but I would remove this ↵ enter symbol on this way.

Create some function in your angularjs controller with regular expression to check if your string contains ↵ like:

```
  $scope.hasEnter = function(str) {
        var enter= /\n/gi;
        if (enter.test(str)) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    };
```

And if this is true, just replace it with character that you need.

Hope this idea will be helpfull for you.

Comment: Thanks arman, but i think that the problem is in web api configuration because i try the same code with a mvc controller and works fine.

Comment: The reason could be in which order is executing your code. I have  DDD app structure where my code in AngularJS Controller is executing first, and then the code in RESTful service called in controller. I had also problems with enter symbol in one case and I mastered it on this way.